# create an equal space between labels in the scrollview with swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uilabel

I am creating a menu of the same style as the kiosk play Application 
I would like the same space between labels, for I dynamically creates, I try SEVERAL way but it does not work.

I size of their label and I added the padding but it does work.

Here is the result

[image]

here is my code

```
func menu (value: [String]){

    var pos: CGFloat   = 50.0
    var index: Int = 0

    for index = 0; index < value.count ; index++ {

        self.titleLabel = UILabel()
        self.titleLabel.text = "\(value[index])"
        self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "MarkerFelt-Wide", size: 20)
        self.titleLabel.sizeToFit()

        //width of the label
        var widhtLabel = self.titleLabel.frame.size.width

        // add padding
        self.titleLabel.frame.origin.x = widhtLabel + pos

        self.scrollViewMenu.addSubview(self.titleLabel)
        pos += 150.0
        println()
    }

    self.scrollViewMenu.contentSize = CGSize(width:  self.titleLabel.frame.origin.x + 220, height:0)
}
```

thanks

Comment: So you're going to want to do something like finding the width of the container you're working with, then subtract with width of all the menu option views.  You will end up with the potential space between all of the views, and you'll want to divide that by your (number of menu options-1).  Then increment `pos` by that value and add the subviews

Comment: So if I understand it will be something like that : `scrollViewMenu.frame.size.width / 2 - widhtLabel / nbItems`

Comment: `distanceBetweenLabels = (scrollViewMenu.frame.size.width - (widthOfAllLabels)) / (nbItems-1)`